# Using Wget with buggy URL

Tags: bash, cygwin, wget

I've got the following link, which is downloading a CSV file when put through a web browser.

```
http://pro.allocine.fr/film/export_classement.html?typeaffichage=2&lsttype=1001&lsttypeperiode=3002&typedonnees=visites&cfilm=&datefiltre=
```

However, when using Wget with Cygwin, with the command below, Wget retrieves a file, which is not a CSV file, but a file without extension. The file is empty, that is, has no data at all.

```
wget 'http://pro.allocine.fr/film/export_classement.html?typeaffichage=2&lsttype=1001&lsttypeperiode=3002&typedonnees=visites&cfilm=&datefiltre='
```

So as I hate to be stuck, I tried the following as well. I put the URL in a text file and used Wget with the file option:

inside fic.txt

```
'http://pro.allocine.fr/film/export_classement.html?typeaffichage=2&lsttype=1001&lsttypeperiode=3002&typedonnees=visites&cfilm=&datefiltre='
```

I used Wget in the following way:

```
wget -i fic.txt
```

I got the following errors:

```
 Scheme missing
 No URLs found in toto.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I can suggest some other options that will make your underlying problem more clear which is that it's supposed to be html, but there is no content (content-length = 0).

More concretely, this

```
wget -S -O export_classement.html 'http://pro.allocine.fr/film/export_classement.html?typeaffichage=2&lsttype=1001&lsttypeperiode=3002&typedonnees=visites&cfilm=&datefiltre='
```

produces this

```
Resolving pro.allocine.fr... 62.39.143.50
Connecting to pro.allocine.fr|62.39.143.50|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Server: nginx
  Date: Fri, 28 Mar 2014 09:54:44 GMT
  Content-Type: text/html; Charset=iso-8859-1
  Connection: close
  X-ServerName: WEBNX2
  akamainocache: no-store
  Content-Length: 0
  Cache-control: private
  X-KompressorName: kompressor7
Length: 0 [text/html]

2014-03-28 05:54:52 (0.00 B/s) - ‘export_classement.html’ saved [0/0]
```

Additionally the server is tailoring it's output based on how the browser identifies itself.  using wget does have an option to include an arbitrary user-agent in the headers.  Here's an example what happens when you make wget identify itself as Chrome. [Here's a list of other possibiities](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php).

```
wget -S --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36" 'http://pro.allocine.fr/film/export_classement.html?typeaffichage=2&lsttype=1001‌​&lsttypeperiode=3002&typedonnees=visites&cfilm=&datefiltre='
```

Now the output changes to export.csv, with type "application/octet-stream" instead of "text/html"

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Server: nginx
 Date: Fri, 28 Mar 2014 10:34:09 GMT
 Content-Type: application/octet-stream; Charset=iso-8859-1
 Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 Connection: close
 X-ServerName: WEBNX2
 Edge-Control: no-store
 Last-Modified: Fri, 28 Mar 2014 10:34:17 GMT
 Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=export.csv
```

Comment: Hi waTeim, thanks for your answer. However, how come that when I put my url link to a web browser, it does retrieve a file?

Comment: @AndyK The server returns 200/OK, so there is no error.  There is a URL which makes one think there is a file on the server called export_classement.html which the -O option forces wget to write to  export_classement.html locally, but that's arbitrary.  The file contains nothing.

Comment: Can you try with the following link on a web browser, please? `http://pro.allocine.fr/film/export_classement.html?typeaffichage=2&lsttype=1001&lsttypeperiode=3002&typedonnees=visites&cfilm=&datefiltre=`

Comment: I was thinking about it but most likely, there is hidden variable in the URL that is put into the URL through the web browser and not through the wget. This is the only reason I can see.

Comment: Cheers waTeim, it is absolutely fine now. Thanks again.